# How to run ReactDomServer.renderAsStaticMarkup in electron main process

Tags: reactjs, electron

I want to run ReactDomServer.renderAsStaticMarkup inside main process in my electron app. But, the jsx syntax is not allowed in main process.

Is there a way to do so?

Comment: why would you want to run this in main process instead of the renderer process?

Comment: Because I need to process the generated markup later with node modules and renderer will not work for it

Comment: have you tried performing the renderToStaticMarkup in the renderer process and sending the result back to main using IPC?

Comment: That’s doable but there are some other native dependencies .